Dell Latitude 7450 Laptop does not recognize the camera
I have bought a Dell Latitude 7450-165 H laptop and the camera is not detecting initially. And I performed the below steps and they are detecing the camera, but after that, I get a black screen not giving any images.

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-engineers/oem-projects-meta
sudo apt install oem-somerville-tentacool-meta
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo systemctl poweroff

Could someone please help me here...

What prompted you to install the ppa app?

Can you check if it works with 24.04? Usually new versions of Ubuntu have better support for new hardware

By installing oem-somerville-tentacool-meta you have replaced your Dell Latitude 7450 - specific drivers from oem-somerville-oddish-meta with their equivalents designed for the Dell XPS 13 9320.
This has a good chance to break existing device support.
According to Dell, the MIPI Webcam is unsupported in Ubuntu 24.04 (as stated 11 Oct 2024).
For the correct drivers, you'll want to head to oddish (hardware support for Dell Latitude 7450/7650), instead of tentacool (hardware support for Dell XPS 13 9320).
